# using easing with effect() in jqueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to apply easing to a specific jqueryUI effect() and can't get it to work. According to this page, it should, but there are no code details:

http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/effect/

I've tried:

```
$("#id").effect( "pulsate", {easing: "swing"} );
$("#id").effect( "pulsate", {"swing"} );
$("#id").effect({effect: "pulsate", easing: "swing"});
$("#id").effect( "pulsate", "swing" );
$("#id").effect( effect: "pulsate", easing: "swing" );
```

None work.

Answer (score 3):

Recently, jQuery UI came out with a new website.  In general, I've found it to be unhelpful at best and inaccurate at worst.  I'm not sure that I'd trust the new site in this case since the [jQuery effect docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Pulsate) for `pulsate` does not describe the same options.

If you want to just `swing` this particular element, you could use this code:

```
$("#id")
.animate({height: "hide", width: "hide"}, 1500, "swing")
.animate({height: "show", width: "show"}, 1500, "swing");
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/3kUm7/1/) of my suggested code in action.

If you'd like to do something else, say more and we'll try to help.

Comment: For more on easing demos, try this site : http://ralphwhitbeck.com/demo/jquery-ui-easing-effects-demo-and-documentation/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#id').effect( "highlight",{color:'#FFFF00',easing:'easeInExpo'},4000 );
```

I am using effect for highlighting an element after a scroll to event. easing is working for me in the above code.

I am running jQuery 1.8.